# Firebase rules to give read permission based on other related data not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So I'm making a calendar app using Firebase, and I've come across a little snag.

My DB structure is like this:

```
- calendar
  - $year
    - $month
      - $day
        - $uid
          - name
          - arrivalStatus
- users
  - $uid
    - name
    - team
```

So what I want to do is that people on the same team must be able to read each other's entries in the calendar.  I've set the rules up like this:

```
{
 "rules": {
   "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
   },
   "calendar": {
    "$year":{
     "$month":{
       "$day":{
        "$uid":{
          ".read": "auth != null && 
                    root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/team').exists() && 
                    root.child('users/'+$uid+'/team').val() == root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/team').val()",
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

But for whatever reason, when running it through the simulation, the request is approved no matter what team you are on.  Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT:

So basically let's assume this dataset:

```
-firecalender
 -calendar
  -2016
   -9
    -30
     -gsdfgd
      -Name: "MG"
      -Status:"PM"
-users
  -abcd
    -name: "Tester"
    -team: "bc"
  -efg
    -name: "noteam"
    -team: "funny inc"
  -gsdfgd
    -name: "bossman"
    -team : "bc"
```

In this situation,  abcd should be able to read each gsdfgd's info inside Calendar, but efg should be denied access.

Comment: Have you tried changing the name of $uid in the security rules. Right now you use $uid in two places, maybe firebase can't see the difference.

Comment: Can you show an operation (with the exact path, data and active uid) that you'd like to fail and the underlying data that it succeeds on?

Comment: Basically calendar/2016/9/30/gsdfgd/ should be allowed if the UID is abcd or gsdfgd but be denied if the UID is efg

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you are using `==` instead of `===`.

Link for examples: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security